# Using prebuilt native .so library from java in Android Studio using experimental gradle plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have added 2 .so prebuilt libraries to a new project in Android Studio which is using the experimental gradle plugin (com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-beta5).

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    repositories {
        prebuilt(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            gstplayer {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file("libs/libgstplayer.so")
                    sharedLibraryFile = file("libs/libgstreamer_android.so")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.myexample.gstreamertest2"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 19
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            buildConfigFields {
                create() {
                    type "int"
                    name "VALUE"
                    value "1"
                }
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.pro'))
            }
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName "gstplayer"
        }

        productFlavors {
            create("flavor1") {
                applicationId "com.app"
            }
        }

        // Configures source set directory.
        sources {
            main {
//                jni {
//                    source {
//                        srcDirs = ['src/main/jni']
//                    }
//                }
                jniLibs {
                    dependencies {
                        library "gstplayer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Gradle build is successful, but I can't find instructions anywhere on how to reference these libraries. I know that you can create `public native String getInfoFromJni()` in your Java file and reference native .c files in your jni folder, and I have been able to get this working, but I don't know how to do something similar with .so libraries.

How do I access the methods in the .so libraries from java?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a wraper c lib:

1.- Change the name of the moduleName to avoid conflicts:

```
ndk {
     moduleName "gstplayerwrapper"
    }
```

2.- Load your wrapper lib in your activity

```
static{

    System.loadLibrary("EcoLogSIL");

}
```

3.- Built your project

4.- Create a function which call the wrapper and press alt+intro

[image]

5.- You should have a new function inside gtsplayerwrapper.c and here you can call libgstplayer.so

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_your_activty_name_call_1wrapper(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

    // YOUR CODE HERE

}
```

Don't forget to import the library inside gtsplayerwrapper.c

**EDIT** add headers

```
repositories {
        prebuilt(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            gstplayer {
                headers.srcDir "src/main/jni/include"
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file("libs/libgstplayer.so")
                    sharedLibraryFile = file("libs/libgstreamer_android.so")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Create this folder in your project and copy there .h files

Comment: That sounds good, but the part I'm struggling with is importing the library in gstplayerwrapper.c and calling libgstplayer.so

Comment: The first error I can see It's that you don't add the headers of your library in gradle file.

Comment: The .so libraries are quite extensive and are a third-party library I'm not very familiar with. How do I know which .h files I need? There are hundreds in this library. I've added the "include" directory from the third-party library and when I make in Android Studio there are tons of #include errors. For whatever reason using ndk-build in command line builds successfully, but when I add these .h files to my jni and build in Android Studio the majority of the the `<example.h>` cannot be found if they are referencing other files in the folder.

Comment: To clarify my last comment with an example, I include a file `gstplayer.h` in my `gstplayerwrapper.c`. To do this I bring `gstplayer.h` into my src/main/jni/include folder. `gstplayer.h` has a line `#include <gst/gst.h>` where gst.h is supposedly in at least one of the 2 .so files I have in my jniLibs, however when I build I get the error **gst/gst.h: No such file or directory**

Comment: Did you check the third party library web site? It's not using experimental gradle but maybe you can figure out how to do it or ask there: http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+Android+development

Comment: And also a simple example: http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Android+tutorial+1%3A+Link+against+GStreamer

Comment: That's actually not the gstreamer website, [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) is. I've been working with it for a while but only recently I was trying to get it working with gradle and Android Studio. There is a demo app [here](https://github.com/sdroege/gst-player) that I can build with `ndk-build` and make an apk with `ant debug`, but nobody has made one with gradle

Comment: @MarkyDD You shouldn't need to add individual headers. You definitely don't want to copy headers into your project--keep them where they are. The section on NDK dependencies in the experimental plugin docs might help: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-NDK-Dependencies